# Prediction based on descriptive text columns

Tags: python, prediction

I am newbie to the Python. I am trying to predict the safety column (output: true/false) by training the model.

I have the following columns:
8D: Object,
HL_description: Object,
Appriasal description: Object,
Detail description: Object,
Safety: Boolean

Could anyone please guide how can I predict the safety column with the help of 1st four columns?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# Import dataset:
dataset = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\HPS1RT\Downloads\test\Safety_Prediction.xlsx",nrows=10000)
dataset[["Safety"]] *= 1
# Assign values to the X and y variables:
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values
# Split dataset into random train and test subsets:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0) 
vect = CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(X_train.ravel())
train = vect.transform(X_train.ravel())
train.toarray()
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", random_state=42,max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)   
clf_model.fit(train,y_train) #Predictions on Testing data
y_predict = clf_model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my code above. I wanted to predict the Safety column using these columns. 8D: Object, HL_description: Object, Appriasal description: Object, Detail description: Object.

 I am getting the error as
ValueError: Number of labels=8000 does not match number of samples=32000.
It's because the shape of train gets changed when I convert the text description into numerical and that does not matches with y_train.

Any idea to resolve the error or any effective solution than this method?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add the complete error log trace please?

Comment: Before you perform prediction on the test set you need to transform the X_test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the `X_test` before you perform inference on the same. Here is the working code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# Import dataset:
dataset = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\HPS1RT\Downloads\test\Safety_Prediction.xlsx",nrows=10000)
dataset[["Safety"]] *= 1
# Assign values to the X and y variables:
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values
# Split dataset into random train and test subsets:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0) 
vect = CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(X_train.ravel())
train = vect.transform(X_train.ravel())
train.toarray()
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", random_state=42,max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)   
clf_model.fit(train,y_train) #Predictions on Testing data
test = train = vect.transform(X_test.ravel())
y_predict = clf_model.predict(test)
```

Comment: runfile('C:/Users/HPS1RT/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/HPS1RT/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HPS1RT\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    clf_model.fit(train,y_train) #Predictions on Testing data
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 890, in fit
    super().fit(
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 272, in fit
    raise ValueError("Number of labels=%d does not match "
ValueError: Number of labels=8000 does not match number of samples=32000

Comment: I am getting the same error. Because when I transform the X_train, the shape of it gets changed to (32000, 10996), whereas the y_train remains as (8000,)

Comment: You should probably post some sample data, it's hard to understand from this error.